# Arranging to keep same letters together

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many different ways can you arrange the letters of the word HALLELUJAH so that all the A’s are together and all the L’s are together?
3 L’s and 2 A’s should be considered as one letter respectively. So 7 letters in total. There are 2’H. Also 3 L’s and 2 A’s can be arranged in 2! ways. Is the answer (7! * 2!) / 2! ?

Comment: Treat what you have to keep together as one (of one kind). And then arrange.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 2!? Both $AALLL$ and $LLLAA$ are already counted in $7!$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $2 H, 2 A, 3 L, 1 E, 1 U$ and $1 J$. You can treat $2$ letters $A$ as $1$ letter $A^*$ and $3$ letters $L$ as $1$ letter $L^*$. So we will have $2H, 1A^*, 1L^*, 1E, 1U$ and $1J$, so 7 "letters" in total. We can have $7!$ arrangements for those "letters". But there are $2H$, so the result must be divided by $2!$ which is $\dfrac{7!}{2!} = 2520$

The $A^*$ and the $L^*$ arrangement, that you said can be arranged in $2!$ ways, is already included in the $7!$